# JSP MVC Model 2 Architecture Question

Tags: java, model-view-controller, jsp, architecture

I want to develop a web application and I have access this API. In the API there are methods that allow you to get the userId of the current user via context objects. Maybe I'm overthinking this, but I'm very confused as to where to put my CurrentUserId() method. Does that method go in the controller or the model? I was thinking it goes in the model, but it seems redundant to write a property called "getUserId" to return a string called getUserId().toString(). Is this normal and I'm overthinking or am I correct? My co-worker told me to put the logic in the view, but from everything I've read you never put java code or scriplets in the view. I hope this makes sense.

Also here's a method I wrote to return the userId as a string

```
protected String CurrentUserId(HttpServletRequest request)
{
    ContextManager ctxMgr = ContextManagerFactory.getInstance();
    Context ctx = ctxMgr.setContext(HttpServletRequest request);

    Id userID = ctx.getUserId();
    return userID.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should go to **Controller**.

Create a utility class having this method as `static`

Because here `HttpServletRequest`  is this model specific(jsp,servlet) , suppose tomorrow if you want to apply the same model to your desktop application then it would fail so better place is controller.